# Does node js spawn(child_process) has a specific time beyond which it dies?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node js server with express on top. I am creating a `child_process().spawn` to run a shell script from node. The script does some task which takes roughly about 5 minutes of time.

I have the following snippet to send the command line output to the browser in the response,

```
app.get(''/runScript', function(req, res){
    command = spawn('./processScript.sh');

    command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log('stdout:'+data.toString());
       res.write('stdout: ' + data.toString());
    });

    command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log('stderr:'+data.toString());
       res.write('stderr: ' + data.toString());
    });

    command.on('close', function (data) {
       res.end();
    });
}
```

The shell script prints a lot of intermediate messages on the command line.

The console log doesn't go beyond a few intermediate messages. Does the request expire after a certain amount of time? I am not using sessions.

Comment: Can you show a larger context of the code include where you spawn the shell script?  If you are writing this to an http request from a browser (which it looks like from the `res.write()`), then the browser itself will timeout the connection at some point and stop waiting for more data from the server.

Comment: And, it turns out that the http module that Express uses also has a timeout for each request: https://contourline.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/preventing-server-timeout-in-node-js/

Comment: @jfriend00 it is a http request from a browser. It is a get request and response is rendered to the browser. I will edit the question to add the complete context.

Comment: If you're missing data from the `console.log()` in node.js, then your problems probably have nothing to do with request timeouts.  I'd suggest you just mode this spawn code into a simple stand-alone node.js app and make sure you can capture all the output from your process into `console.log()`.  This would remove any request timeout issues for the moment to see where your issue is most likely.

Comment: I can see there is some issue like this for a spawn. some times it takes a lot of time to spawn despite you wrote to already spawned application.